# Create unique pairs of numbers within a range and store as objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, unique

Basically, I want to create all unique pair combinations of objects from numbers 1-20. But critically I don't want a repeat of the same numbers in a pair in a different order (so not a full factorial for example not:
`{num_set_one: 1, num_set_two: 2} {num_set_one: 2, num_set_two: 1})`

I would want something like this:

```
array = [
{num_set_one: 1, num_set_two: 1}
{num_set_one: 1, num_set_two: 2}
{num_set_one: 1, num_set_two: 3}
{num_set_one: 1, num_set_two: 4}]
...
{num_set_one: 19, num_set_two: 20}
{num_set_one: 20, num_set_two: 20}
]
```

Any tips would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you have an attempt or code we can build off of?

Answer (score 0):

Just use nested loops:

```js
const array = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i ++) {
    for (let j = i; j <= 20; j ++) {
        array.push({num_set_one: i, num_set_two: j});
    }
}
```